# x264: How to Correctly Use quant_offsets?

Tags: video, encode, x264, libx264

Suppose I need to encode different regions with different QPs in one frame, i.e. RoI(regions of interest) encoding. I searched all over the internet and was only told that `quant_offsets` can meet my demand. However, none of them told me exactly how to use it, and I can't find any official documentation about it. I read the source code of x264 and did experiments, and find it only adds an offset to the qp decision x264 has made, rather than exactly set the qp value I want.

Is there a possible way that I can have x264 encode these regions using the qp value I've explictly given instead of adding offsets based on what it decided on its own? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally get my answer after studying the source code of x264. I found modifying the `h->mb.i_qp` in the loop of `slice_write()` can meet my demand.

Yet, it makes me feel frustrated that there are few people working on AV, and oftentimes I can't find any right answer on the Internet or have the opportunity to tend to professionals for my questions during my learning time.